# The Talkative Badge?

Tags: support, bug, chat

I just received notification that I have earned the Talkative Badge for posting 10 messages in Cross Validated chat rooms with one or more of them starred. I can recall only one message that I have ever posted in the Ten Fold chat room (I did it just a few days ago), and it certainly does not seem to be starred in any way (or being, to my mind, really deserving of a star).  Searching the chat rooms for any other messages that I might have posted did not reveal any older messages that I had forgotten about.

So what is this Talkative badge, and why have I been awarded it?

Comment: That's odd. It looked like it worked right when I got it. I imagine that it also counts also one-on-one discussions generated by answering questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/18?m=18314881#18314881) be the message?

Comment: Yes, that is the message that I posted recently. But, for the life of me, I cannot recall posting 9 messages in Cross Validated chat rooms before that, and I cannot find the previous 9 by searching the Cross Validated chat rooms. Perhaps a long time ago, a one-on-one discussion regarding a question or an answer got moved to chat (as per @Glen_b's comment), and that chat room is now closed and not searchable by me?

Comment: That's almost certainly the answer, @DilipSarwate.

Comment: @gung is correct: I have searched all your chat posts, Dilip, and found several rooms created for one-off conversations on "Show Me the Money," "Cryptography," "Signal Processing," and the math sites, totaling about 30 posts.  I unfroze the math room (at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7738/discussion-between-dilip-sarwate-and-chris) so you can see it again; it will automatically freeze again after two weeks of non-use. Because only one post is in a CV chat site, I am guessing that the badge tracks your chat at *all* SE sites, not just in CV-related rooms.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for letting me look at that chat room; yes, I guess that was indeed a protracted conversation with a student who was having a _lot_ of difficulty, and I had completely forgotten about it. The badge does seem to track chat across all SE sites since in that room, my reputation shows as more than 44K: far more than on any single site. I guess I _am_ talkative.... and will shut up for now and accept Skilvvz's answer so that this thread can be closed.